# Visual Studio 2017: not all projects loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# Visual Studio solution that contains 195 projects. I noticed some projects failed to be loaded (it shows "unavailable" besides the project name), howeever from the context menu we can choose to select "install missing feature(s)" to load the projects manually and compile them one by one.

The question is, why Visual Studio (I use 2017 professional) couldn't load ALL projects once and for all in the first place? Is it a bug with the IDE?

Comment: if the folder structure changes, it can cause the projects to not be found, in which case you usually need to unload the projects and then load existing projects. My guess is the folder structure changed

Comment: When you select "install missing features" what does it do?  I've seen this happen before when a solution has a project written in a language that VS doesn't support out-of-the-box and it needs a plugin/extension installed to work.  After that though, it "just worked" for me.

Comment: if you do not have the required features to build on such projects, what would be expected to happen?

Comment: unload the projects (unloaded project) then load again

Answer (score 1):

Install missing features will install any .NET SDKs that you may be missing. For example, if one of your projects targets .NET Core 2.2 but you don't have that installed, "Install Missing Features" will install it for you. Or it could also be project types.